# Opencart: How to get the code of a shipping method

Tags: php, opencart

I am developing a shipping module of Opencart.

I have reviewed the source code of the template for shipping module as below.

```html
<?php foreach ($shipping_method['quote'] as $quote) { ?>
  <tr class="highlight">
    <td><?php if ($quote['code'] == $code || !$code) { ?>
      <?php $code = $quote['code']; ?>
      <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>" id="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>" checked="checked" />
      <?php } else { ?>
      <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>" id="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>" />
      <?php } ?></td>
    <td><label for="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>"><?php echo $quote['title']; ?></label></td>
    <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>"><?php echo $quote['text']; ?></label></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
```

However, I am not sure if I am adding a new shipping method, where should I set/get the $quote['code'].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shipping codes are set in the respective shipping method's model file, found in

```
/catalog/model/shipping/your_shipping_name.php
```

There are a number of methods that come bundled with OpenCart that will show you how to do this. You'll want to look at the `$quote_data` variable in particular. It's worth noting that if you're wanting to have more than one method for your type of shipping, such as 24 hour, standard delivery etc then it gets a little more complicated. Here's an example

```
                $quote_data['surface'] = array(
                    'code'         => 'royal_mail.surface',
                    'title'        => $title,
                    'cost'         => $cost,
                    'tax_class_id' => $this->config->get('royal_mail_tax_class_id'),
                    'text'         => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($cost, $this->config->get('royal_mail_tax_class_id'), $this->config->get('config_tax')))
                );
```

This is the `royal_mail.php` file's shipping method (one of them). Pay particular attention to how the code key has `royal_mail` followed by the `.` to separate it from this particular method `surface`. You'll also notice that `surface` is the array key for the quote itself in `$quote_data`. This is necessary to distinguish between methods. For example, should you wish to add a new shipping method called `foo` to the Royal Mail shipping method, you would do

```
                $quote_data['foo'] = array(
                    'code'         => 'royal_mail.foo',
                    'title'        => $title,
                    'cost'         => $cost,
                    'tax_class_id' => $this->config->get('royal_mail_tax_class_id'),
                    'text'         => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($cost, $this->config->get('royal_mail_tax_class_id'), $this->config->get('config_tax')))
                );
```